# Soap.XSBuiltIns.XMLTimeToDateTime conversion

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am using XMLTimeToDateTime as time conversion function for datetime fields in JSON. I am seeing an unexpected conversion by this function. It seems to try to do some kind of UTC time to local time conversion, even though you tell it not to.

Here is some test code (in DUnit):

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Soap.XSBuiltIns,
  System.DateUtils;

procedure TestXMLTimeConversion.TestXMLTimeToDateTime;
var
  ReturnValue: TDateTime;
  testDate: TDateTime;
begin
  testDate := EncodeDateTime(2014, 3, 2, 3, 12, 45, 0);
  ReturnValue := XMLTimeToDateTime('2014-03-02T03:12:45', False);
  CheckEquals(testDate, ReturnValue, 'ReturnValue: ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:nn:ss', ReturnValue));
end;
```

This returns

```
ReturnValue: 2014-03-02T04:12:45, expected: <41700,1338541667> but was: <41700,1755208333>
```

If you change the Boolean parameter of XMLTimeToDateTime to True, the conversion becomes correct. I would have expected the reverse to be the case. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Edit:

I dug around a bit and I believe I have found the cause of this. From the specifications of varius ISO8601 profiles I could find on the internet, one of them being [this one from W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), it seems to be the case that systems might expect time zone indication to always be available any time a timestamp is specified.

If you append a time zone indication this to the test case, it computes the correct time (in this case I adjust to CET).

```
procedure TestTXSDateTime.TestXMLTimeToDateTimeWithTimeZone;
var
  ReturnValue: TDateTime;
  testDate: TDateTime;
begin
  testDate := EncodeDateTime(2014, 3, 2, 3, 12, 45, 0);
  ReturnValue := XMLTimeToDateTime('2014-03-02T03:12:45+01:00', False);
  CheckEquals(testDate, ReturnValue, 'ReturnValue: ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:nn:ss', ReturnValue));
end;
```

This leaves the case where no timestamp is specified. This should be legal and I would expect this to result in a datetime value with the fraction set to 0, no matter which time zone you are in.

```
procedure TestTXSDateTime.TestXMLDateToDateTime;
var
  ReturnValue: TDateTime;
  testDate: TDateTime;
begin
  testDate := EncodeDateTime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  ReturnValue := XMLTimeToDateTime('2014-03-02', False);
  CheckEquals(testDate, ReturnValue, 'ReturnValue: ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:nn:ss', ReturnValue));
end;
```

However XMLTimeToDateTime still adjusts for local bias in this case, which in my opinion is a bug. If you live in the US or anywhere else that is behind UTC this means that you get a TDateTime value with a day portion corresponding to the day before the one actually given.